# Using 12-Factor Configuration Standard in a Python (Django) Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, configuration

I am currently learning practices from the [12-Factor guide](https://12factor.net/) using one of the Django apps that I am running in production.

In short, after reading the theory and doing my best to understand the work of [`django-environ`](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) package, I have attempted to eliminate in-code configurations from `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` files.

I am soliciting feedback on the progress thus far and possible ways to improve the situation.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

**1. `settings.py`**

```
import os

import environ
root = environ.Path(__file__) - 2 # three folder back (/a/b/c/ - 3 = /)
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),) # set default values and casting
environ.Env.read_env() # reading .env file

SITE_ROOT = root()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG') # False if not in os.environ
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
CLOUD = env('CLOUD', default=False)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static")

#This should be commented out in Development
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static"),
  #public_root.path('static')
]

COMPRESS_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "media")

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db(), # Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if DATABASE_URL not in os.environ
    'extra': env.db('SQLITE_URL', default='sqlite://db.sqlite3')
}

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

from oscar import get_core_apps
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar.defaults import *

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',

    'mod_wsgi.server',
] + get_core_apps()

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

if env('CLOUD') and env('ALLOWED_HOST'):
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(env('ALLOWED_HOST', default=''))
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(env('ALLOWED_HOST_ALIAS', default=''))

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_name.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'),

            #re-route the search for templates into this custom template directory
            os.path.join(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates'), 'tshirt-theme'),

            #Uncomment the line below to restore the original Oscar template
            #OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'promotion_tags': 'custom_oscar.templatetags.promotion_tags'
            }
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_name.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}

USE_LESS = False

OSCAR_INITIAL_ORDER_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_INITIAL_LINE_STATUS = 'Pending'
OSCAR_ORDER_STATUS_PIPELINE = {
    'Pending': ('Being processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Being processed': ('Processed', 'Cancelled',),
    'Processed': ('Shipped','Cancelled',),
    'Shipped':(),
    'Cancelled': (),
}
```

**2. `wsgi.py`**

```
from app_name.settings import env, SITE_ROOT 
CLOUD = env('CLOUD', default=False)

# if not in the local development env
if CLOUD:
    import sys
    import site

    path = SITE_ROOT
    #path='/var/www/vhosts/app/app-site'
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    #Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
    #site.addsitedir('/var/www/vhosts/app/app-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
    site.addsitedir(env('PYTHON_ENV_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR'))

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app_name.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**3. `.env`**

```
DEBUG=on
CLOUD=False
ALLOWED_HOST=localhost
ALLOWED_HOST_ALIAS=localhost
# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.dev
SECRET_KEY=asdglkjasd;kljasd;fkljadsf
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite3
# SQLITE_URL=sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db
```